# Is there a way to change <script src=??> url value in chrome and reload page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a js file that is used in my html code as follows:

```
<script src="//some-website/files/CURRENT_JS_FILE.js" async></script>
```

I do not have a QA environment, nor the ability to change the html code in production

I would like to test my updated js code as follows:

1) inspect html
2) update source file url:

```
<script src="//some-website/files/NEW_JS_FILE.js" async></script>
```

3) 'soft' refresh page to test locally (reload page, but with new js file url)

Is there a way to do this? I attempted the following with no good results:

1) Update the  src url, press refresh (refreshed the whole page and the src url as expected)

2) Press CMD+P, opened the JS file in question, updated the code, saved; refreshed again but no-go.

Comment: Try a hard reload?

Comment: Can you create whatever page that is using the file and just name it something different so you can change stuff on the page without breaking prod

Comment: Setup wireshark to intercept the traffic :)

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb What is a "hard" reload?

Comment: @ Huangism and Jonas W. There are actually 30+ versions of said JS file (loaded dynamically)... and my project manager was hoping to QA them this way... So no, creating one page or teaching him wireshark unfortunately are not viable.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+R` (or `Cmd+Shift+R`)

Comment: Have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/950087/1016716)?

Comment: Then I guess you can set it up so a url query param can be used to define the file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to do this this way :

1. Go to your web page
2. View source-code
3. Copy and paste it to a new file.html or whatever on local

If this shows you the "correct" page design, then now you can copy/paste your js file the same way, change the import of js in your file.html and make your trys

Comment: I ended up using resourceoverride chrome extension, but this method works as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides).

1. Go to `chrome://version`. Make sure that you have Chrome 65 (when the feature was introduced).
2. Open **Sources** panel.
3. Open the **Overrides** tab.

   [image: Local Overides tab]
4. Click **Select Folder For Overrides**.
5. Select a directory, then click **Allow** to give DevTools access to read and write to that directory.
6. Edit your HTML file in the **Sources** panel. *NOT* the **Elements** panel. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the change.
7. Reload the page. DevTools serves the local version of the file that you just modified, rather than the network version.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the Resource Override chrome extension which works as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `eval` and `XMLHttpRequest`. But if you use that way, you can't use `document.currentScript`.

```
<script src="/your-source.js" id="script-characteristic"></script> 
<!-- Set after loading -->
<script>
var scriptElement = document.getElementById("script-characteristic");
if (scriptElement.innerHTML != "") {
    eval(scriptElement.innerHTML);
} else if (scriptElement.src && scriptElement.src != "") {
    var scriptRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    scriptRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            eval(this.responseText);
        }
    }
    scriptRequest.open("GET",scriptElement.src,true);
    scriptRequest.send();
}
</script>
```